# Unable to run any async ajax requests after location.replace is called in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, ajax, webkit, comet

I have a loading page that uses location.replace to navigate to the result page. This request can take a long time, so it takes a while to return. In the meantime, I am using long-polling ajax requests to update the loading page with progress information.

This works fine on Firefox and IE, it allows ajax requests to continue after location.replace is called.

But with webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari), all the ajax requests are canceled once the location.replace request is executed.

Is there a way to make ajax requests while the main window is navigating to another page in webkit browsers?

Answer (score 0):

if your using ajax maybe you can download the page with a ajax call and just render its boddy into the active page and change the curent url witch webkit suports.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to avoid doing it that way if possible because the result page is rather large. Might end up going that route in the future, but for now, I'm hoping for something that will work with navigating to a new page.